# Edit and save features on a database in ArcGIS JS API

Tags: javascript, editing, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I create a map by using Esri JS API and try to edit my building features. I want to create new features (or delete them) on the map and I want to save changes on my database. How can I do that?

```
    require([
  "esri/Map",
  "esri/views/SceneView",
  "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
  "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
  "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
  "esri/widgets/Expand",
  "esri/Graphic"
], (Map, SceneView, GraphicsLayer, SketchViewModel, FeatureLayer,Expand,Graphic) => {
  // the layer where the graphics are sketched
  const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer({
    elevationInfo: { mode: "on-the-ground" },
    title: "Sketch GraphicsLayer"
  });

  
  //arcgis_______________________________________________
  const extrudedBuildings = new FeatureLayer({
    url:
        "https://arcgis.geotech-company.com/server/rest/services/Hosted/Hacettepe_Buildings/FeatureServer",
    renderer: {
        type: "simple",
        symbol: {
            type: "polygon-3d",
            symbolLayers: [
                {
                    type: "extrude",
                    material: { color: [255, 237, 204] },
                    edges: {
                        type: "solid",
                        color: [133, 108, 62, 0.5],
                        size: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        visualVariables: [
            {
                type: "size",
                field: "yukseklik",
                valueUnit: "meters"
            }
        ]

    },
    visible: true
});

const map = new Map({
  basemap: "dark-gray-vector",
  layers: [graphicsLayer, extrudedBuildings],
  ground: "world-elevation"
});

const view = new SceneView({
  container: "viewDiv",
  map: map,
  camera: {
    position: {
      x: 32.734444, //Longitude
      y: 39.867222, //Latitude
      z: 2400 //Meters
  },
  heading: 356.82,
  tilt: 55
  },
  qualityProfile: "high"
});

  const blue = [82, 82, 122, 0.9];
  const white = [255, 255, 255, 0.8];

  // polygon symbol used for sketching the extruded building footprints
  const extrudedPolygon = {
    type: "polygon-3d",
    symbolLayers: [
      {
        type: "extrude",
        size: getvalue(), // extrude by 10 meters
        material: {
          color: white
        },
        edges: {
          type: "solid",
          size: "3px",
          color: blue
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  // // polyline symbol used for sketching routes
    const route = {
    type: "line-3d",
    symbolLayers: [
      {
        type: "line",
        size: "10px",
        material: {
          color: white
        }
      },
      {
        type: "line",
        size: "3px",
        material: {
          color: blue
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  // point symbol used for sketching points of interest
  const point = {
    type: "point-3d",
    symbolLayers: [
      {
        type: "icon",
        size: "30px",
        resource: { primitive: "kite" },
        outline: {
          color: blue,
          size: "3px"
        },
        material: {
          color: white
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  
  // load the default value from the snapping checkbox
  let snappingcheckboxsavedstate = enabledcheckbox.checked ? true : false;

  // define the SketchViewModel and pass in the symbols for each geometry type
  // set the snappingOptions.selfEnabled to the default state
  const sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
    layer: graphicsLayer,
    view: view,
    pointSymbol: point,
    polygonSymbol: extrudedPolygon,
    polylineSymbol: route,
    snappingOptions: {
      enabled: snappingcheckboxsavedstate,
      featureSources: [{ layer: graphicsLayer }] 
    },
    tooltipOptions: { enabled: true },
    labelOptions: { enabled: true },
    defaultUpdateOptions: {
      tool: "reshape"
    }
  });

  // after drawing the geometry, enter the update mode to update the geometry
  // and the deactivate the buttons
  sketchViewModel.on("create", (event) => {
    if (event.state === "complete") {
      startbuttons.style.display = "inline";
      actionbuttons.style.display = "none";
      sketchViewModel.update(event.graphic);
    }
    if (event.state === "cancel") {
      startbuttons.style.display = "inline";
      actionbuttons.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  sketchViewModel.on("update", (event) => {
    if (event.state === "start") {
      startbuttons.style.display = "none";
      actionbuttons.style.display = "inline";
      if (
        event.graphics[0].geometry.type === "polygon" ||
        event.graphics[0].geometry.type === "polyline"
      ) {
        edgeoperationbuttons.style.display = "inline";
      }
    }
    if (event.state === "complete") {
      startbuttons.style.display = "inline";
      actionbuttons.style.display = "none";
      edgeoperationbuttons.style.display = "none";
    }
  });

  

  cancelBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    sketchViewModel.cancel();
  });
  
  doneBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (sketchViewModel.updateGraphics.length !== 0) {

      sketchViewModel.complete();

    } else {
      sketchViewModel.cancel();
    }
  });

  view.ui.add("sketchPanel", "top-right");

  // Call FeatureLayer.applyEdits() with specified params.
function applyEdits(params) {
  addFeatureBtnDiv.style.display = "true";
  addTemplatesDiv.style.display = "none";
  unselectFeature();

  featureLayer
    .applyEdits(params)
    .then((editsResult) => {
      // Get the objectId of the newly added feature.
      // Call selectFeature function to highlight the new feature.
      if (editsResult.addFeatureResults.length > 0) {
        const objectId = editsResult.addFeatureResults[0].objectId;
        selectFeature(objectId);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("error = ", error);
    });
}


});
```

Comment: How is your database / layer hosted (ArcGIS Online, Enterprise On-Premise)?

Comment: ArcGIS Online .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to include the editor widget in your app and use it. For example you can check this nice example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-editor-basic/

```
// Set the layer's LayerInfo 
const myLayerInfos = {layer: myLayer,
  formTemplate: { // autocasts to FormTemplate
    elements: [{
      type: "field",
      fieldName: "Id",
      label: "ID"
    }, {
      type: "field",
      fieldName: "Status",
      label: "Status"
    }]
}};    
// Editor constructor 
const editor = new Editor({ view: view, 
  layerInfos: [myLayerInfos] 
}); 
// Add the widget to the view 
view.ui.add(editor, "top-right");
```